# Salary and academic career in Italy

Tags: career-path, job-search, salary, italy

What are the average salaries for the steps of an academic career in Italy (RTDa, RTDb, Associate Professor, Full Professor)? In the vacancy announcements that I've seen, this information was not included. Are there any tables containing this information? Are the salaries or bonuses individually negotiated or fixed nation-wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are essentially fixed nation-wide, apart from a minor portion of local taxes.

[Here](https://www.unipi.it/index.php/costi-e-tabelle-retributive/item/2036-tabelle-retributive-del-personale-docente-dellateneo) are the tables for my university. Labels are in Italian, but "Costo a.l. Amm." means "gross yearly salary", and "tempo pieno" means "full-time". You get a raise every three years.

Comment: Thank you! Roughly speaking, what is the tax percentage to be applied on the gross salary?

Comment: I think it's going to be around 50% on that number when you factor in everything. For a more accurate estimate, sum up the "stip. a.l.", "I. I. S. a.l." and "A. A. a.l." columns, subtract [income tax](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imposta_sul_reddito_delle_persone_fisiche#Presupposto_e_caratteristiche_dell'imposta) which has several brackets, and toss in about 100E/month of additional local taxes.

Comment: Also, there are some child benefits, but I am not familiar with them, having no children myself.

Comment: At the end of the day, my net salary is more or less what is in the first column of that table. This might be an accurate rule-of-thumb, apart from the RTD-B table which seems to be built differently.

Comment: Another thing that is probably not clear at a first read is that the various rows for professor positions essentially represent career years. In your first year you'll get what the first line says, then the second line, and so on. So raises are every three years, essentially.

Comment: I realize it's complicated, especially for a foreigner. :/ I know very little about the intricacies of salary laws myself, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks again! So, roughly speaking, we range from 1500/month for starting rdta to 7000/month for the most senior full professors -- is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, that seems accurate, at least for the RTD-A; possibly a little more (1700-1800). I am not really sure because my assistant position was a different type under a previous law. I have never asked a senior full professor what their net salary is. :) I suspect the very end of that table is difficult to obtain, because you'd need to become full professor very early.

Comment: I am full professor since 2015, my net salary is around (a bit less) 4000 Euros…